# MySQL Results in 3D Array PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am a novice in PHP. I have the following snippet from my PHP Code

```
  $select = "SELECT budgetname,SUM(budgetamount) AS budget,sqlitebudgetid FROM budget WHERE budgettype = 'INCOME' AND budgetaccount = '$budgetAccount' AND budgetuser = '$userID' AND budgetdate BETWEEN '$fromDate' AND '$toDate' GROUP BY BudgetName ASC";

 $result = mysqli_query($con, $select); 

       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {             

        $rowIncomeBudgetLabels[] = $row["budgetname"];          

        $rowIncomeBudgetAmounts = array($row["budget"],$row["budget"], row["sqlitebudgetid"]);          

       }
```

I have tried to put the last part $rowIncomeBudgetAmounts  into the following array but the result only display the first line.

I tried as below but id not working :

```
  $data = array($rowIncomeBudgetAmounts);
```

Want to put to an array as below : so that each line is displayed as a separate sub array. Please help.

```
$data = array(  array( 255, 100, 100 ),
              array( 100, 255, 100 ),
              array( 100, 100, 255 ),
              array( 255, 255, 100 ),
            );
```

EDIT >>

I am getting the following results ; instead of several lines - I am only getting the first line. On the graph all descriptions are showing but without all corresponding figures.

[image]

PERFECT : This is the result I wanted : Thanks @Ultrazz008

[image]

Comment: please provide array you are getting from select query....

Comment: Select query gives me a result table with 3 columns ie(budgetname, budget and sqlitebudgetid) - I want as an example to put all digits from all columns as shown in the $data array above.

Comment: @IshmaelChibvuri Edit your post and show us the result that you are getting. so based on this result we can suggest you a proper way to handle this

Comment: I have edited.. Hopefully it make sense now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the line from:

```
$rowIncomeBudgetAmounts = array($row["budget"],$row["budget"], row["sqlitebudgetid"]);
```

to:

```
$rowIncomeBudgetAmounts[] = array($row["budget"],$row["budget"], $row["sqlitebudgetid"]);
```

And you will get array of array data, appended `[]` at the end of `$rowIncomeBudgetAmounts`, and the `$` missing from the `row["sqlitebudgetid"]`

And after that use:
`$data = $rowIncomeBudgetAmounts;`
to get the:

`array( array(), array(), array() )` - of your data.

Here's the way you wish it, and the code i posted in answer how it works:

http://ideone.com/2nuMyw

Comment: You just don't need the `$data = array($rowIncomeBudgetAmounts);`, the code i posted and change this to `$data = $rowIncomeBudgetAmounts;` it should be the same array as you posted it.